# Need to implement an alert function to make a pop up window for sum of all numbers

Tags: javascript

So my code has all the math done, but when I click the button it uses HTML to add the sums, but I need a popup window with the math on it and that uses javascript. I will send code and screenshots so you are not confused on what it is supposed to look like.

My code:

```js
function sumOfNumbers() {
  var theNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtNumber").value);
  if (theNumber > 0) {
    var theSum = 0;
    for (var num = 1; num <= theNumber; num++) {
      theSum += num;
    }

    document.getElementById("theSum").innerHTML = "The sum of all the numbers from 1 to " + theNumber + " is " + theSum;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("theSum").innerHTML = "Enter positive number please!";
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtNumber">
<input type="button" value="Calculate Sum" onclick="sumOfNumbers()" />

<br>

<div id="theSum"></div>
```

Image of what it is supposed to look like:

[image: 1]

As you can probably see, when you click the sum button it just has my lettering under it saying how many sums it is, but I need that pop up box to say the sums. Please let me know if anyone can help! Thank you very much.

Comment: It's just a matter of using `alert()`: what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried alert() in different spots, but I'm also just learning java in school so im new to it. I have seen that you can only put a message in the (), but I almost need some type of formula or sum in it

Comment: I think I need an alert() for both the if and else statements but I dont know what to put inside of it.

Comment: `alert("The sum of all the numbers from 1 to " + theNumber + " is " + theSum)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to just replace this

```js
document.getElementById("theSum").innerHTML = "The sum of all the numbers from 1 to " + theNumber + " is " + theSum;
```

with this

```js
alert("The sum of all the numbers from 1 to " + theNumber + " is " + theSum);
```

You may do the same for the `else` part.

Here's a live demo:

```js
function sumOfNumbers() {
  var theNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtNumber").value);
  if (theNumber > 0) {
    var theSum = 0;
    for (var num = 1; num <= theNumber; num++) {
      theSum += num;
    }
    /** call "laert" to show the result. You may customize the message the way you want */
    alert("The sum of all the numbers from 1 to " + theNumber + " is " + theSum);
  } else {
    alert("Enter positive number please!");
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtNumber">
<input type="button" value="Calculate Sum" onclick="sumOfNumbers()" />
<br>
<div id="theSum"></div>
```

Comment: My code still isn't working even with the updates which is weird because it works on here